# Store ID displayed with Static Block

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

I have included a Static Block called "home-center-contact" for 4 different Store Views with the ID's '**14**', '**19**', '**16**' and '**18**'.

Why am I seeing the number on my homepage along with the Static Block? Including the default Store View, which I am **NOT** including "home-center-contact" on?

Here is the code I have added to "**home.phtml**":

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-promotion')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php echo $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
 if($storeId == '14')
{ $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
}
if($storeId == '19')
{ $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
}
if($storeId == '16')
{ $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
}
if($storeId == '18')
{ $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
} ?>
```

Store Views with "home-center-contact":

https://beaconbingo.kellyseye.com/

https://cashino.kellyseye.com/

https://tanexpress.kellyseye.com/

https://merkurengineering.kellyseye.com/

Store View **NOT** Including "home-center-contact" but including "home-center-promotion":

https://store.kellyseye.com/

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-promotion')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    if($storeId == '14')
    { 
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
    }
    if($storeId == '19')
    { 
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
    }
    if($storeId == '16')
    { 
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
    }
    if($storeId == '18')
    { 
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-center-contact')->toHtml();
    } 
?>
```

According to the logic of the code all stores you have mentioned will show the same static block.

Answer (score 0):

if you check your code you have echo that's why display store id please change below line.

```
 <?php echo $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

so just remove **echo**.